# DATE_ADD problem

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am working to add 1 month to date() and save it in my field on database.

I use this

```
$query2 = "SELECT * ,DATE_ADD(`date_joined`,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS expire FROM `set` WHERE ID='$idno'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
```

"expire" is the field i want to save as +30 days. 
date_joined is current date.

but it doesn't work. 
expire field is still current date
no error message.

what should i do?

or is there another way to add 30 days to current date and save it as my "expire" field ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not including why it does not work as for example the error message from the database?

Comment: cuz there is no error message

Comment: What do you mean when you say "save?"  Do you mean that you want to add the field to the table?  Is there an `expire` field in the table already?  Are you trying to do an `update`?

Comment: yeah sorry, it is about my english, i mean update, i want to update this expire field as current date + 30 days
there is expire field already with the current date

Comment: You need an `update` statement.  I've added an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a comma between the asterisk and the `DATE_ADD` call.  It should look like this:

```
SELECT  *,
        DATE_ADD(`date_joined`, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS expire 
FROM    `set` 
WHERE   ID='$idno'
```

Once you fix that, the query looks well formed.

**Edit:**  It sounds like you need an `update` statement, not a `select` statement.  Try:

```
update `set`
set    `expire` = date_add(`date_joined`, interval 30 day)
where  `id` = '$idno'
```

Comment: Is `date_joined` a field of `date` or `datetime` type?

Comment: Add to your question your updated code and the results you are getting.

Comment: this time, expire field is 0000-00-00 :S

Comment: What is the value of `date_joined` in that row?  Is it null?

Comment: omg ok it works now, i should have used ` instead '
thx again

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad we solved your problem.  You don't need to use any quotes around that identifier.  You only need to use backticks when your field names are keywords or you have special characters in your table name.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement.

```
UPDATE `set` SET expire = DATE_ADD(date_joined, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
WHERE ID='$idno'
```

Comment: The single quotes around `date_joined` need to be backticks.

Comment: +1 because you posted this before I edited my answer (sorry about that).

Comment: Thanks, and +1 to you for picking up the problem with back ticks.